# Where are the original files?

Tags: git, visual-sourcesafe, version-control

I’ve created a repository, looked at what Git created, and can’t find the files anywhere under the .git tree. So, how do I know my files are safely stored in Git?

Comment: You don't need to introduce yourself with every question.  There's a link to your profile.

Answer (score 1):

Which files?

Git doesn't store duplicates of the files. The contents of a Git repository's `.git` directory is essentially a database of all the content tracked by Git, along with commits, tags, and so forth.

If your repository is a non-bare repository, it will have a *working tree* associated with it. The working tree is the most current representation of the files tracked by Git.

Comment: So, no longer using SCM (Source Code Management) for backup, eh?

Comment: Well, given a `.git` repository, Git can easily create a working tree with a simple `git checkout`.

Comment: I would not recommend using any SCM as backups in general.  I also wouldn't recommend using a backup system as an SCM.  The .git directory contains everything you need to reconstruct every version of every file you've ever committed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also clone the repository to see that you get what you expect.